# Kendo MVC cancel form submission - form always submits

Tags: javascript, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a way to cancel a form submission via Javascript when using Telerik Kendo MVC. The code I have doesn't work, I can't figure out how to prevent the form submission - it always submits.

I have a classic MVC form:

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateApplication", "Home"))

with

and the following JS:

```
$("form").kendoValidator({
    validate: function (event) {

        var errors = this.errors();

        if (errors.length > 0) {
            showErrors(this.errors());
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            if (! checkCostCode() || !checkApplication()) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The methods checkCostCode() and checkApplication() return false, yet the form still submits.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    kendo.culture("en-GB");

    $("form").kendoValidator({
        validate: function (event) {

            var errors = this.errors();

            if (errors.length > 0) {
                showErrors(this.errors());
               event.preventDefault();
            } else {

                if (!checkCostCode()){
                    isValid = false;
                }

                if (!checkApplication()) {
                    isValid = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $("form").submit(doSubmit);
});

function doSubmit() {
return isValid;
}
```

Comment: or you could just return `isValid`